# Meaning of "stockpile of smelling salts was on hand to accommodate fainters"

Tags: past-tense

> Steven Houghton, a theater employee, said a stockpile of smelling salts was on hand to accommodate fainters.

It is a sentence I read in New York Times. Stockpile of smelling salts was on hand to accommodate fainters, i don't seem to understand this particular line. The word "accommodate" is used, why is it used? Doesn't it mean to provide room for someone. Am i missing something here?

Comment: The various meanings of the verb *accommodate* are easily found in dictionaries,  [to give what is needed to someone](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/accommodate) ; [to provide with something desired, needed, or suited](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodate), etc...

Answer (score 1):

[accommodate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodate) takes this meaning:

> transitive verb
> 1
> to provide with something desired, needed, or suited

> I needed money, and they accommodated me with a loan.

> ... a stockpile of smelling salts was on hand to accommodate fainters.

means a stockpile of smelling salts was on hand to be provided for fainters.

The definition you have mentioned is also found in the same dictionary but is not applicable here.